# Copy first row values to other rows on GridView in windows Form application

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a WinForm application and on this Form I have following controls.

```
1-Grid view
2-Copy button
```

-How can I put only 1 Button (copy Button)just beside the 1st row of the grid view ?
-How can I populate first row and make other 16 rows same as my 1st row after click the copy button? But Only different is ID that gets the incremented value.

**Example:**

```
ID   Explanation  Teacher_ID
---  -----------  ----------
0    hello        45         CopyButton
1    hello        45
2    hello        45
3    hello        45
.    .            .
.    .            .
.    .            .
16   hello        45
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a lookup class

```
  public class LookUp
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Explanation { get; set; }
        public long TeacherId { get; set; }
    }
```

On button click

```
   private void ClickEvent()
    {
        //Use correct columnId or name here
         var name = dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[2] != null ? dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[2].ToString() : "";
         var id = dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[3] != null ? long.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[3].ToString()) : 0;
         var datalist = GetList(name, id, 16); //you have a copy of values with diffrent ids -- rest is for you
    }

  //create a method which return copy of values but with different id
    private IEnumerable<LookUp> GetList(string name, long id,int till)
     {
        for (var i = 1; i <= till; i++)
         {
           yield return new LookUp() { Id = i, Explanation = name,TeacherId = id};                    
          }
     }
```

Comment: error: var name = .....( Column named 2 cannot be found.)  Column named 2 cannot be found.
Parameter name: columnName

Comment: This is just an example.... so I guessed the column id, use the actual column id's for `Explanation` and `Teacher_ID` columns or Column names to get values!!!

Comment: Input string was not in a correct format. Error coming up now

Comment: @user2827565: It seems you have a very little understanding about what you are doing!!! sorry cannot help further. use `try-catch` and see what is the problem, check the data type... I suspect the id data type is something else than int/long